# Have common column but different row numbers in both sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have a set of datas in different excel sheets.

Both sheets have one column in common. Column name: name in sheet 1 and name(class) in sheet 2 )

Sheet 1: Column name:

- Name, Class, Gender

Sheet 2: Column name:

- Name(class), Subject, Grade

I want to be able to click on the cell in any sheet and direct me to sheet3 where relevant data related to that selected cell shown. For example, if i were to click on a name in sheet 1 , that name and the related data to that name will be shown in sheet 3. Row numbers for names in sheet 1 and sheet 2 are different.

**CODES:**

```
DetailsUsedRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Rows.Count

With ActiveCell
    Name = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(.Row, 9) 
    NoName = InStr(1, "(" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(.Row, 1) & ")", (Name)) 
    MsgBox NoName 
    MsgBox Name 
    For i = DetailsUsedRows To 1 Step -1 
        If (NoName <> 0) Then ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Student Viewer").Cells(2, 3).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(.Row, 1).Value
..... 
        end if 
    next i
```

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]

i want it to display like this. But the name(IC) is preventing me to get the various data under the same name and ic

Comment: This is indeed possible using VBA but what have you tried so far. Where are you stuck? In your attempted code, do you encounter errors? This is kinda broad if you ask me. At least try something first and we will start there.

Comment: Please edit your question and add your code there. Use `edit` below the tags.

Comment: @l42 sorry im new to this. The above codes was part of the codes that i did, but it didnt work.

Comment: Would it not be easier to do this as a VLOOKUP in VBA? So you would take the activecell. Put the name and class onto sheet 3 and merge them to match sheet 2 and then do a vlookup in VBA to give you the subject and grade

Comment: @Sam I was thinking of using other method but that is ok :). You can post it as solution.

Comment: @SherryKong Does your data in Sheet1 and Sheet2 begin in Row1? I mean the headers are in Row1? I was thinking of another solution besides what Sam pointed out.

Comment: @SherryKong, I have updated my answer to fix my problem with the code. Should work fine now, you will need to change things around a bit to get it to work most likely though with sheet names etc

Comment: @L42 my header start from row 3

Comment: @SherryKong What other information reside in Row1 and Row2? Blank? Empty? Or what?

Comment: @L42 I only put a Macro button to clear the filter. Other than that , nothing.

Answer (score 0):

My idea would be to use a vlookup in vba with a dynamic range.

```
Dim i As Long, k As Long

i = Sheets("sheet2").UsedRange.Rows.Count

k = 1

With ActiveCell

    Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A2") = ActiveCell & "(" & ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1) & ")"

    For J = 2 To i
        k = WorksheetFunction.Match(Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A2"), Sheets("sheet2").Range("A2:A9"), 0) + k
        If k > i Then
            Exit For
        End If
        Sheets("sheet3").Range("A" & J) = Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A2")
        Sheets("Sheet3").Range("B" & J) = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Sheets("sheet3").Range("A2"), Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & k & ":C" & i), 2, 0)
        Sheets("Sheet3").Range("C" & J) = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Sheets("sheet3").Range("A2"), Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & k & ":C" & i), 3, 0)
    Next
End With

Sheets("sheet3").activate
```

You will need to change the references to the sheets and possible ranges used. But what my code does it, is it will take the activecell. Take the Name and the Class and put them in the format "Name(Class)" then paste onto sheet3("A2"). Then do a vlookup on sheet2 to find any matches with the name, then give the subject and grade in the next columns on Sheet3.

EDIT updated code to fix count problem

Comment: No need to do a instr in the name(class) column in sheet 2 with name column in sheet 1 ?

Comment: I have problem in the 
    'k = WorksheetFunction.Match(Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A2"), Sheets("sheet2").Range("A2:A9"), 0) + k'

The error shows that Unable to get the match property of the worksheetfunction

Comment: I had an error a couple of times but that was because I had not set anything to be on sheet3 in A2. And you will most likely need to change your range from A2:A9. To what ever you range is going to be. You can keep it at A2 and then just need to get the last cell. So it should only break if there is nothing on A2 in sheet3, or it does not match anything in Sheet2. So you should first check to see what value is in A2 on sheet3.

Answer (score 0):

Assumptions:

1. Both Sheet1 and Sheet2 start at Row 3 (Header), actual data start at Row4.
2. Output is transferred in Sheet3 first row (A1).

This goes to a regular module (e.g. `Module1`)

```
Sub Get_Data(val As String, source1 As Worksheet, _
        source2 As Worksheet, dest As Worksheet)
        
    Dim lr As Long
    With source1
        lr = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        With .Range("A3:C" & lr)
            .AutoFilter 1, val
            .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy dest.Range("A1")
        End With
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
    
    With source2
        lr = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        With .Range("A3:C" & lr)
            .AutoFilter 1, val
            .Offset(0, 1).Resize(, 2).SpecialCells( _
                xlCellTypeVisible).Copy dest.Range("D1")
        End With
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
End Sub
```

This goes to your *Sheet1* code module.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error GoTo halt
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Dim r As Range, lr As Long
    
    With Me
        lr = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Set r = .Range("A4:A" & lr)
        Sheet3.Cells.ClearContents
        If Not Intersect(Target, r) Is Nothing _
        And Len(Target.Value2) <> 0 Then
            Get_Data Target.Value2, Me, Sheet2, Sheet3
            Sheet3.Activate ' Just to view Sheet3
        End If
    End With

moveon:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
halt:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume moveon
End Sub
```

Now if you want the same effect in *Sheet2* you also need to add the same event in it.
Take note that you need to add just the parameters in `Get_Data` sub like this:

```
Get_Data Target.Value2, Sheet1, Me, Sheet3
```

Btw, `Sheet1, Sheet2 and Sheet3` are sheet codenames.
That is the default when you create a new workbook.
Now to check if you are using the correct codename, you need to check it in the properties window.

[image]

So this happens whenever a name is selected. If you want to put more control, you can transfer the `Selection_Change` code in `Double_Click` event. So you will only view the record if you double click the name.

Comment: but i have many sheets to combine in one master sheet. Like taking various fields from different sheets to show in one master sheet. So if i do your method for module, do i need to create the codes again and again in module ?

Comment: @SherryKong Above solution only works if you are to combine 2 worksheets as you have described in your question. Other scenarios would be deemed out of scope although it can still be done.

Comment: So if i want more than 2 worksheets is impossible. I thought it will be the same so that why i gave only 2 worksheets. Opps.

Comment: @SherryKong It is possible, but the approach would be different. What I'm saying is above approach is only applicable in the scenario you described in your question. Since you didn't mention it in your question in the first place, that makes it out of scope.

Comment: I understand thanks. So from the above codes, how do i change it to apply for more worksheet.

Comment: @SherryKong There are a lot of considerations and approach will differ on how you're data is organized for every sheet. If the lay-out is the same for all sheets (Column containing the name is always at the far left - Column A) then it would be possible to just use a single source worksheet argument and then just loop through all the sheets you want to pull data from passing it to the `Get_Data` sub routine. If not, then another approach will be needed.

Comment: Only one sheet is different from the rest. The rest of the sheets, 3 columns are the same. Sheet1 contains the particulars of each person. The rest's 3 common column are about name, student id and diploma. The common column with sheet1 is the IC number in the Name column. For example, Name(S1233456V) ...

Comment: @SherryKong Ok, please illustrate as sample lay-out. I just need to be sure before I amend the updates on the my answer.

Comment: @SherryKong Excellent. So it is the `Student ID` field that is common. And you only click the name in `Particulars` Sheet? Your display is a bit complicated. I mean the lay-out. What if the student have more than one diploma? Or is that just a sample lay-out and can be altered?

Comment: Sorry the particulars do not have student id column. And i can only click on the IC number in the particulars sheet.